# Can you put a font awesome icon on a before, that already has a ::before class on the selector?

Tags: html, css, transition

i have a menu bar with 4 links. i want a different font awesome icon before my links, while still having my border hover effect. It seems like when i put another class or id on the element, the font-awesome icon still doesn't take affect. The only solution im coming up with now is having each of the 's have their own class, to target them specifically; but that sounds like more code, and i'm sure i can still achieve what im set out to do.

I noticed

```
a#home .main-links {
content: "\f101"
visibility: visible doesnt work.
}
```

So to summarize what im trying to achieve is putting the "ICON" before my one of my links, while still being able to use the border-bottom transition. 
i've also tried to use two classes as well.

```css
a.main-links {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 0;
  color: #66fcf1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.main-links:hover {
  color: #45829e;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a.main-links::before,
a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  background: #45829e;
  width: 0%;
}

a.main-links::before {
  left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

a.main-links::after {
  right: 0;
  background: #45829e;
  transition: width 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
}

a.main-links:hover:before {
  background: #45829e;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1);
}

a.main-links:hover:after {
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-ul">
  <li class="main-li">
    <i class="fas fa-home">
            <a id="home" class="main-links">home</a>
    </i>
  </li>
  <li class="main-li">
    <a class="main-links">resume</a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-li">
    <a class="main-links">about</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the border transition using another technique then you can use the pseudo element.

Here is an idea using gradient:

```css
.link {
  font-size:30px;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#45829e,#45829e);
  background-position:bottom left;
  background-size:0% 2px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:
   background-size 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.22, 0.61, 0.36, 1),
   background-position 0s 0.8s;
}

.link:hover {
  background-position:bottom right;
  background-size:100% 2px;
}

.link:before {
  content:""
}
```

```html
<span class="link">Text</span>
```